# WPF textbox style issue

Tags: wpf, xaml

Can anyone explain why the TextBox resource style of `CornerRadius` works just fine, but BorderThickness and BorderBrush have zero effect?

```
<TextBox Text="TextBox with CornerRadius but no thickness and color" 
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
         VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
         VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="500" Height="100">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">                
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that in the standard `TextBoxBase`'s template the Border control has its properties `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush` bound to the same properties of the `TextBox` itself.

Here the standard ControlTemplate used in the style:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
    <cbd:ClassicBorderDecorator x:Name="Bd" BorderStyle="Sunken" Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}">
        <ScrollViewer Name="PART_ContentHost" />
    </cbd:ClassicBorderDecorator>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" Property="theme:ClassicBorderDecorator.Background" />
            <Setter Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" Property="Control.Foreground" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

So to reach your target those properties can be set in this way:

```
<TextBox Text="TextBox with CornerRadius but no thickness and color" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="30" BorderBrush="Red"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="500" Height="100">
        <TextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="30" />
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 3):

The BorderThickness and BorderBrush of the Border element in the Template of a TextBox are bound to the respectice properties of the templated control, i.e. the TextBox:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ...>
        ...            
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

These Bindings override the values from any Border Style Setters.

You should set the values in a TextBox Style:

```
<TextBox Text="TextBox with CornerRadius but no thickness and color" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="500" Height="100">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="30"/>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="30"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Sorry but this one's correct, the other says essentially the same but introduces non default/standard elements. +1